# Generate number of random sample of specified length in R

Tags: r, loops, random

I think it's my poor knowledge of R, especially poor knowledge of loop-related codes.

Here is what I am trying to do. Assuming I have numbers from 1 to 500. first, generate 300 sets of two randomly picked numbers  from 1 to 500, assign to each set  a number from 1 to 300, and then combine them into one dataset, let it be dataset A.

So A will look like

```
A_no  random_num
1       26
1       256
2       3
2      113
...
```

Then I need to create a dataset B where I will have sets of 3 random numbers out of 500, also counted

```
B_no  random_num
1       16
1       113
1       4
2       67
2       25
2       7
```

I believe the R code will look very elegant and simple.  Will really appreciate any help with this solution.

Comment: I'm confused ... the random numbers are between 1 and 300 or between 1 and 500?  And there's 300 of each, or 500 of each?  Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I have total of 500 numbers and need to generate 300 random samples.

Answer (score 0):

This is simplifying somewhat, taking advantage of the (assumed) fact that all randomly picked numbers will be independent.

```
df1 <- data.frame(A_no=rep(1:500,each=2), random_num=sample(1:300,2*500,replace=T))
head(df1)
##   A_no random_num
## 1    1        249
## 2    1        117
## 3    2        108
## 4    2         44
## 5    3        138
## 6    3        247

dim(df1)
## [1] 1000   2

df2 <- data.frame(A_no=rep(1:500,each=3), random_num=sample(1:300,3*500,replace=T))
head(df2)
##   A_no random_num
## 1    1        276
## 2    1         50
## 3    1        237
## 4    2        153
## 5    2        225
## 6    2          4

dim(df2)
## [1] 1500   2
```

Comment: Matt, this one is probably even better. I'll play with both outputs. I guess the last one will work better with larger number of random numbers. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Set random seed
set.seed(83)
# Generate sequence
z <- seq(1, 300)
# Generate first sample
x <- sample(1:500, 300)
# Combine
zx <- data.frame(z, x)
# Set seed again
set.seed(82)
# Generate second sample
x <- sample(1:500, 300)
# Combine
zy <- data.frame(z, x)
xyz <- rbind(zx, zy)
```

Or you could do this way

```
# Set random seed
set.seed(83)
# Generate sequence
B_no <- seq(1, 300)
# Generate first sample
x <- sample(1:500, 300)
y <- sample(1:500, 300)
z <- sample(1:500, 300)

wide <- data.frame(B_no, x, y, z)

library(reshape2)
B <- melt(wide, id.vars = c("B_no"))
Bx <- B[order(B$B_no),]
```

Comment: Thank you! Got your answer when I was trying to write two story function. Of course it should be that simple. I just need to assign counts, as the resulting data has unique values assigned to each random number, from 1-600. But I'll figure out the rest. Thank you!!!

Comment: Glad it worked.  If you are happy with the answer, you should consider marking the checking mark green to close the question.

Comment: The second version is a real beauty. Works perfectly. I didn't know about reshape2 library, appears to be very useful. Thank you very much.